# jScrollPane overrides absolute positioning, how do I re-enable?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to use the `jScrollPane` described here:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

```
<body>
     <div class="scroll-pane"
         <div id=titletext>
              Title of Content In Scroll Pane
         </div>
         <div id=maintext>
              Content of scroll pane.
         </div>
     </div>
<body>
```

What I am trying to acheive is to have "Title of Content In Scroll Pane" stay positioned at the top of the scroll pane as the user scrolls up and down. When i was using the default scroll bar the css for the `titletext` using:

```
positon: absolute;
```

was doing the job, however this is no longer the case after the addition of `jScrollPane`. How do I get this working? I tried to add the following to my javascript but it was no help.

```
$('#titletext').css({
    position: 'absolute',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**1st method**, set the `titletext` *outside* your jScrollPane wrapper:

```
<body>
     <div id=titletext>
           Title of Content In Scroll Pane
     </div>
     <div class="scroll-pane"
         <div id=maintext>
              Content of scroll pane.
         </div>
     </div>
<body>
```

**2nd method**, use a fixed positioning:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#titletext').css({
    position: 'fixed'
});
```

or even better, use `CSS:`

`#titletext{position:fixed}`